# how save the properties of android controls?

Tags: android, properties, save

I have implemented an application for save the properties of android content view.

I have used check box for enable and disable a editText.When user check the the check box then i am enabling edit text view and when user unchecked the check box then disabling edit text.Here if user check the check box then edit text view will be enable for enter data then the user click on save button then the edit field propertie as enabling will save if user re lunch the app

I have implemented code for it as follows:

```
 ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setEnabled(false);

    ((CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
            ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setEnabled(true);
            }
            else{
                ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });

    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //here how to save the properties of editText1 and checkBox1 upto re-launch


        }
    });
```

If user re open the application the modified content only will appear.

Please any body help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean("editTextState", editText.isEnabled());
    outState.putBoolean("checkBoxState", checkBox.isEnabled());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        editText.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("editTextState"));
        checkBox.setEnabled(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("checkBoxState"));
    }
}
```

Or you can use SharredPreferences.

In your Activity:

```
private EditText editText;
private CheckBox checkBox;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                editText.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                editText.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });

    loadProperties();

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveProperties();
        }
    });

}

private void saveProperties() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putBoolean("CHECK_BOX_STATE", checkBox.isChecked());
    editor.putBoolean("EDITEXT_STATE_STATE", editText.isEnabled());
    editor.commit();

}

private void loadProperties() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    checkBox.setChecked( prefs.getBoolean("CHECK_BOX_STATE", false));
    editText.setEnabled( prefs.getBoolean("EDITEXT_STATE_STATE", false));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but can i implement the above code in button event?

Comment: These methods (onSaveInstanceState, onRestoreInstanceState) will be called before your activity is created and before it gets killed. So actually you dont have to implement this functionallity in a button event. If you want to save information when your button is pressed than you can use sharedPreferences. You can find a link in my answer above

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is:[onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

This method makes it possibile to save for example all information of your controls.

Another possibility would be to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

```
    SharedPreferences settings = this.context.getSharedPreferences("myPreferences", 0);
    // read stored value
    String storedValue = settings.getString("aKey", null);

    // store/override value
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("aKey", "aValue");
    editor.commit();
```

Comment: how to apply when click on save button.please give some clarification

Comment: I added a code example for sharedPreferences. The example from @appserv and this one should be enough for you to get it run.